# NullPointerException on invalidateOptionsMenu even though checked for null

Tags: android

In Logcat I see a very interesting NullPointerException:

```
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu()' on a null object reference
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at de.widmer.offerings.fragments.SongbookFragment.toggleMenuAndProgressBarVisibility(Unknown Source:17)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at de.widmer.offerings.fragments.SongbookFragment.r0(Unknown Source:0)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at de.widmer.offerings.fragments.SongbookFragment$2.onCompleted(Unknown Source:15)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.tonyodev.fetch2.fetch.ListenerCoordinator$mainListener$1$onCompleted$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:359)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7418)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
08-30 08:20:59.596 16965 16965 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Interestingly, this is the first entry in the Logcat of a real device.

The code of `toggleMenuAndProgressBarVisibility` is:

```
private void toggleMenuAndProgressBarVisibility(boolean enabled) {
    mProgressbarHorizontalLayout.setVisibility(enabled ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    mUpdateOptionsEnabled = enabled;
    if (mContext != null && mContext instanceof Activity) {
        ((Activity)mContext).invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I am checking if the `Context` is null and of instance Activity before I call `invalidateOptionsMenu`. How is a `NullPointerException` even possible here?

Comment: Would need more information to figure out what going on, like where you get the `mContext` object from and also your activity code. Why aren't you using `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();` instead of storing a reference to a `Context` object which is not recommended ?

Comment: That's actually a very good point... honestly, that's probably my lack of Android knowledge. I have now changed the code to ´getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()´. I guess that may have been the problem. But one more question here: I am storing Context in my fragments in `onAttach` and release it in `onDetach`. Is that not recommended?

Comment: I guess that could work but you need the understand the consequences and handle it accordingly. Read [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)